# Is it possible to implement always_false in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

There are cases where one uses an `always_false` helper to e.g. cause unconditional `static_assert` failure if instantiation of some template is attempted:

```
template <class... T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct UsingThisShouldBeAnError {
  static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "You should not use this!");
};
```

This helper is necessary because a template definition must (at least theoretically) have at least one set of template parameters for which a valid specialization can be produced in order for the program to be well-formed:

> [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8): The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template [...] and the template is not instantiated, or
>
> [...]

(Writing `static_assert(false, "You should not use this!");` above would thus be ill-formed and a compiler could always fire the static assert, even without the template being instantiated, which is not the intention.)

Here is a quick sampling of questions involving this pattern (including further explanation):

- [Forbids functions with `static_assert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745581/forbids-functions-with-static-assert)
- [Are static_asserts to be evaluated if a member template isn't instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913556/are-static-asserts-to-be-evaluated-if-a-member-template-isnt-instantiated/42913797#42913797)
- [Conditional compilation of templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468724/conditional-compilation-of-templates)

It might be useful to have `always_false` as a tool in the standard library so we don't have to constantly write it again. However, the answer to the following question makes me wonder whether this is even possible:

[Dependent non-type parameter packs: what does the standard say?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783393/dependent-non-type-parameter-packs-what-does-the-standard-say/57785778)

There the argument is made (also with respect to [temp.res]/8) that `std::enable_if_t<T>` is always either `void` or not a type and that it is illegal for anyone to specialize it further. Therefore, a template that relies on the theoretical "specializability" of `std::enable_if` to avoid the [temp.res]/8 clause actually causes the program to be ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Coming back to my question: If the standard provided `always_false`, it would have to forbid library users from specializing it as usual (for obvious reasons). But by the above reasoning, that would defeat the whole point of `always_false` (namely that it could theoretically be specialized to something other than `std::false_type`) - with respect to [temp.res]/8 it would be the same as using `std::false_type` directly.

**Am I wrong in this reasoning?** Or is it actually impossible for the standard library to provide `always_false` in a meaningful/useful way (without core language changes)?

Comment: the standard library can do things that are otherwise illegal in user code, so I would say yes, it is possible for the standard library to implement such a construct, even if it were illegal otherwise. Don't quote me though.

Comment: @bolov: issue is user's **usage**. class definition is trivial and doesn't have issue. but once in `std`, that imposes extra restriction to user (as no specialization unless allowed).

Comment: @Jarod42 god, C++ can be have such dark corners...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To paraphrase Jarod's idea, It could be something like

```
template <class... T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <> struct always_false</* implementation defined */> : std::true_type{};
```

Where `/* implementation defined */` can be filled by `std::_ReservedIdentifer`. User code can't access it, since the identifier is reserved to the library, but there exists a specialization that is `true`. That should avoid questions about the ODR and lambdas in specializations.

Comment: Accepting this solution because it is more encompassing (and I guess more standard-like).

Answer (score 16):

<strike>In C++20, with lambda, you might do something like:</strike>

```
template <class... T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

// To have true, but for a type that user code can't reuse as lambda types are unique.
template <> struct always_false<decltype([](){})> : std::true_type{};
```

After reflection, I think it is not possible: enclosing template might have other restrictions that the hypothetical type(s) for the specialization should fulfill:

With `static_assert(is_enum_v<T> && always_false_v<T>)`, that type should be an enum.

And even more constrained, with `static_assert(is_same_v<T, int> && always_false_v<T>)`, it is for `int`.

Edit:
C++23 now allows `static_assert(false);` in non instantiated part :)

Comment: Does it really require C++20? Won't something like `std::_UglyTypeWeCannotTouch` will do?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Could be, but not sure that a type like that doesn't break requirement *"without core language changes"*.

Comment: @Jarod42 how about `template <> struct always_false</* implementation defined */> : std::true_type{};` aka unspecified and hidden, not special otherwise.

Comment: What bolov said. That's what those `_Identifiers` are for after all.

Comment: @StoryTeller it was your idea. If you feel like it do the honors with an answer.

Answer (score 3):

All such attempts result in a program that is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The clauses that block you from using `static_assert(false)` make your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required based on the actual possibility of making an actual instantiation, not based on if the compiler can work it out.

These tricks simply make it harder for the compiler to **detect** the fact your program is ill-formed.  The diagnostic they issue **is not required**, and your ability to bypass the diagnostic being issued just means you made the compiler produce an ill-formed program for which the standard places no restrictions on its behavior.

> (Writing static_assert(false, "You should not use this!"); above would thus be ill-formed and a compiler could always fire the static assert, even without the template being instantiated, which is not the intention.)

The exact same conclusion holds for your

```
template <class... T> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct UsingThisShouldBeAnError {
  static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "You should not use this!");
};
```

I claim there is no valid instantiation of `UsingThisShouldBeAnError` in the above program.

http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#6.1

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
> (6.1) no valid specialization can be generated for a template [...]"

No valid specialization can be generated for this template.

To avoid this trap, your program **must** have

```
template <> struct always_false<SomeListOfTypes> : std::true_type {};
```

and if an `always_false` is specified in the standard for which this cannot occur, using `always_false` from the standard doesn't help you at all.
because the standard requires that the specialization "can be generated".

If the only way to instantiate your template is within an ill-formed program, then that is a huge stretch on the word "can".  So using reserved or magic types you aren't allowed to use within the `true_type` specialization is not really plausible.

Stepping back, the purpose of the "ill-formed, ndr" there is because the standard writers want to permit diagnostics of broken code, but don't want to mandate it.  Detecting such broken code in general is a halt-hard problem, but simple cases can be detected.  And optimizing around the assumption that the code isn't broken can be useful.

All attempts to inject `static_assert(false, "message")` are working around the **intention** that C++ code is intended to be valid.

We have a construct for a function for whom successful lookup is an error already in the language.

```
template<class T>
void should_never_be_found(tag<T>) = delete;
```

the hole, of course, is the lack of a diagnostic message here.

```
template<class T>
void should_never_be_found(tag<T>) = delete("Provide an custom ADL overload!");
```

also, the inability to `=delete` template specializations.

What you appear to **want** is:

```
template<class T>
struct UsingThisShouldBeAnError = delete("You should not use this");
```

which is direct, intentional, and consistent with how other `=delete` cases work.

The `static_assert` bypass requires magic and "tricking" the compiler to bypass parts of the standard explicitly written to prevent you from doing what you want to do.

This `=delete("string")` and `=delete` syntax on template classes is missing from the language.

Comment: *"your program must have"*. How much code can be added to make a specialization valid? From your answer, it seems none. Do you mean that SFINAE based on a type_traits (such as `has_foo`) is ill-formed NDR if there doesn't exist a class which fulfills the requirement (`template <typename T> void foo(T& t) -> decltype(t.foo()) { return t.foo(); }` is potentially ill-formed).

Comment: I agree with your overall assessment and your suggestion for the solution (`=delete`) of the overall problem. However the point of the question is to explore the negation of *"if an `always_false` is specified in the standard for which this cannot occur"*: How *can* we specify `always_false` to allow it to occur, in a useful manner (accepting the contradiction to the name)? I believe that `SomeListOfTypes` = `/*implementation defined*/` hits the mark with "there exists at least one legally usable type that results in `true_type`, it's just intentionally hard to name it".

Comment: @MaxLanghof We cannot.  Either the user is allowed to use a type in `SomeListOfTypes` in C++ code, in which case it doesn't satisfy your requirement, or the user code cannot, in which case there is no valid specialization for the template.  Remember, everything within `std` header files is literally magic in C++.  What code constructs in them are valid is not relevant.  I mean, we could go with "the name of the type that works here is implementation defined", but users must be able to name it and using it must be valid.

Comment: Any and *all* hacks around that are either "I am trying to fool the compiler" or "I am trying to confuse or convince the user".  Fooling the compiler fundamentally doesn't work, because the standard is being omniscient here; if the only valid type is one that exists if the Collatz conjecture is true, then your program is ill formed depending on the truth value of the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The point is that there are options between "using the name is forbidden by punishment of ill-formedness, NDR" and "there's a commonly known way to get `std::always_false` to become `std::true_type`". Again, I agree with this being suboptimal (and in the realm of "confuse or convince the user"), but such is life. `std::array` also must have its actual data member public and user-accessible, and the world doesn't come crashing down.

Comment: *"If the only way to instantiate your template is within an ill-formed program,"*. It would not be ill-formed in compiler/std context though. Might that count?

Answer (score -6):

just use option `-fdelayed-template-parsing`

Comment: `-fdelayed-template-parsing` is an option of some compilers to enable non-standard behavior. But my question is about a theoretical addition to the standard library while keeping standard-compliant behavior. It's not even related to compilers.