# if constexpr and dependent false static_assert is ill formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304847/constexpr-if-and-static-assert) provides the example of a type-independent `false` in a `static_assert`:

```cpp
template<class T> void foo()
{
    if constexpr(false)
        static_assert(false);
}
```

However, I am more concerned if the same thing applies to a type-dependent `false`. Here is the relevant quote from the standard:

> The program is **ill-formed, no diagnostic required**, if no valid specialization can be generated for a template or **a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template** and the template is not instantiated. [§ 13.7/8.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res)

This comes as a surprise to me as I frequently see the following idiom:

```cpp
template<class T> void foo()
{
    if constexpr(cond)
        // ...
    else
        static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, T>);
}
```

In fact, cppreference even provides [an example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) of the same thing:

```cpp
template<class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};
template<class T> void foo()
{
    if constexpr (cond)
        // ...
    else
        static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value);
}
```

From my understanding, in both of these cases, no valid specialization can ever be generated for the relevant `if constexpr` substatements, and are therefore ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Am I correct?

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787666/is-it-possible-to-implement-always-false-in-the-c-standard-library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> no valid specialization can ever be generated for the relevant `if constexpr` substatements

Well no.

You could have a valid specialization of that branch if you specialized `dependent_false` first:

```
template <> struct dependent_false<int> : std::true_type {};
///
foo<int>(); // <-- A valid specialization for the `else` branch is possible here
```

The fact that it's possible to create such a specialization (even if you don't have one) makes `static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value);` well-formed.

On the other hand, `static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, T>);` is ill-formed NDR, because specializing templates from `std::` is not allowed.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the cppreference example is actually bad? Because there is no specialization for `int` there. Furthermore, we want to have false every type, `int` should not be an exception. So a better type is the one that Jarod42 used, `decltype([](){})`.

Comment: @geza I'm not saying you need to create a specialization of `dependent_false` to make the code well-formed. I'm saying it's well-formed because you *could* create a specialization.

Comment: @geza Edited for clarity.

Comment: Hmm. Thinking about this again, isn't it the case, that if `cond` can ever be true, then we're good? There is no need to have the possibility that static_assert's condition can ever be true, because if `cond` can be true, there is already a valid specialization.

Comment: On the other hand, if `cond` always false, then we must have a `dependent_false` specialization, where it gives true, because if we didn't have one, all the specializations are invalid. So in this case, it is not enough, that in theory, we could add one, but we need to add one.

Comment: @geza The standard requires that a valid specialization has to exist for each `if constexpr` branch, not only for the entire template.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the info. Then, isn't it the case, that we must add a `true` specialization for `dependent_false`? It is not enough, that we could add, but we must do it? (If we don't add one, then the program is ill-formed, because there is no valid specialization exists for the `static_assert` branch)

Comment: @geza I think we don't have to, but I'm not completely sure. Maybe we should make a new question about it.

Comment: Isn't the gist of this question about this? :)

Comment: @geza Oh well. :)